# Provider was disposed before a value was emitted

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I wrote the following code and encountered the error `The provider AutoDisposeFutureProvider<Data>#d1e31(465-0041) was disposed before a value was emitted.`

I thought it was strange, so I debugged FutureProvider's `onDispose` and found that it was disposed during the await of the API call, which is confirmed by the output of `disposed!`

```dart
class HogeNotifier extends StateNotifier<Hoge> {

  onFormSubmitted(String input) async {
    final value = await _reader(searchProvider(input).future); // The provider AutoDisposeFutureProvider<Data>#d1e31(465-0041) was disposed before a value was emitted.
    // execute by using value
  }
}
```

```dart
final searchProvider =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<Data, String>((ref, value) async {
  ref.onDispose(() {
    print("disposed!");
  });
    try {
      final result = await dataSource.find(keyword: value); //call api asynchronously
      return Future.value(result);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      return Future<Data>.error(e);
    }
});
```

Why does the above error occur? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help solve the problem:

```dart
final searchProvider =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<Data, String>((ref, value) async {

  ref.keepAlive();
  /// do next
});
```

Comment: thank you!  But i have soloved this issue by using ref.watch(searchProvider) instead of read. Do you know why this problem occurred?

Comment: This could be a problem in the future. From the documentation: The watch method should not be called asynchronously, like inside an onPressed of an ElevatedButton. Nor should it be used inside initState and other State life-cycles.
In those cases, consider using ref.read instead.